# Delegate not being set

Tags: objective-c, delegates, delegation

Could someone please help me with the following code:

```
    - (IBAction)addCellButton: (UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if(!self.imagePopover)
    {
        AlbumPicker *albumPicker = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MultipleImagePicker"];
        self.imagePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:albumPicker];
        albumPicker.delegate = self;
        NSLog(@"%@", albumPicker.delegate);
        [self.imagePopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                                  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                  animated:YES];
        self.imagePopover.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

The problem is is that when I check the delegate in my albumPicker.m by printing it, it is set to `nil`?  Am I setting the delegate properly?

Comment: And you're sure `albumPicker` itself is non-nil?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be nil.  I just checked it by printing it's contents.  It is not nil.  And when I print albumPicker.delegate, it is not nil in the above code

Comment: So what is nil?  imagePopover.delegate or albumPicker.delegate?

Comment: In what method in the view controller class are you checking the delegate for nil?

Comment: Are you using ARC? And can you post the code (and surrounding methods) you use to check the delegate?

Comment: @rdelmar albumPicker is null when I print it using NSLog

Comment: Really? You said in your first comment that you could print out the contents of albumPicker, so it can't be null. Did you mean albumPicker.delegate logs null?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have set delegate in the right way. I think if the delegate is working properly, it is probably due to the property of delegate .I vaguely remember that in Google(or Apple) coding guidelines, delegate's property should be set as `assigned` instead of `retain`.

In addition, your question seems to be somehow unclear to me. I think if you want to check if the delegate is working, you'd better set a delegate method and see if the method is called.